# How to get Xcode 3.2.3 to correctly include the SpiderMonkey jsapi.h file?

Tags: c, xcode, xcode3.2, spidermonkey

I have created a C Command Line app in Xcode 3.2.3. I have compiled SpiderMonkey from the command line, and have it working, this was for CouchDB 0.11. The js interpreter works, as well as all the files being in `/usr/local/spidermonkey/include` and `/usr/local/spidermonkey/lib`.  I have added `/usr/local/spidermonkey/include` to my Header Paths, and `/usr/local/spidermonkey/lib` to my library path.

Every time I add the jsapi.h file from the `/usr/local/spidermonkey/include` and reference it in my main.c file, compliation breaks. Why won't the following code compile?

```
#include "jsapi.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the **exact** error the compiler is giving you?

Comment: it is giving me 283 errors :-( something fundamentally wrong is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. For OSX there needs to be a `#define XP_UNIX` before you `#include "jsapi.h"`.
This isn't in any tutorial or examples or anything I can find on Google, but there is now! [How to include SpiderMonkey in your XCode 3.2.3 project.](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2010/06/spidermonkey-in-xcode-3-2-3/) Here is the corrected snippet of code.

```
#define XP_UNIX
#include "jsapi.h"

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, next time include a *few* of the 283 errors and someone might spot it sooner. :)